# Not every matrix on V ⊗ W can be written as a tensor product of a matrix on V and another on W.

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

I am reading some notes about tensor product of vector spaces (those in [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkopC7kuPpAhXCxoUKHXWVCQEQFjAIegQIAhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhitoshi.berkeley.edu%2F221A%2Ftensorproduct.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3P4LcDF_0sUK3n4FrtYtoW)) where the following sentence can be found:

> Note that not every matrix on V ⊗ W can be written as a tensor product
>   of a matrix on V and another on W.

Matrices in V ⊗ W are defined as a Kronecker product. So, how could this claim be possible? Has it to do with the problem of splitting the Kronecker product of two matrices?

More generally: does the general picture changes if we consider V and W infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two elements:

1. If you read the sentence following the one you quote, there is an explanation based on dimensions.
2. Consider a $4 \times 4$ matrix $C$ with only one zero entry. If you try to write $C = A \otimes B$, either none of the $A,B$ entries is equal to zero and then $C$ will have no zero entry. Or they have at least one, and then $C$ will have at least four zero entries.

The second argument can be extended for infinite dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for your clarity. Does this fact mean that not every basis of V⊗W is of the form of a tensor product of a basis of V and a basis of W?

Comment: You can refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78564/basis-for-tensor-products) for some elements.