# Is the tensor product of two vector space on $R$ isomorphic to $R^{d^2}$?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$,$W$ be two fine-dimensional vector spaces  over the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Assume the dimension of both spaces is d.
Is there a unique isomorphism between $V \otimes W$ and $\mathbb{R}^{d^2}$?

ie, can we interpret elements of $V \otimes W$ as being vectors in a $\mathbb{R}^{d^2}$ space?

So on the easiest case scenario, is an element of  $V \otimes W$ just a real number?

Comment: What is the meaning of asserting that $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R^d$, when $d>1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the comment José. just edited the question. Confusion from my side, $V$is a vector over $\mathbb{R}$, the dimensionality of the vector space is d. The elements of $V$ can be interpreted as $\mathbb{R}^d$ vectors

Comment: If both $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces (over the same field), then  $V\otimes W$ will also be a vector space, which has dimension $\dim V\times \dim W.$ (If finite.)

Comment: Also, since both $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic to some $\mathbb R^{d_1}, \mathbb R^{d_2}$, one has isomorphisms between them, respectively. You may try to use the universal property of $V\otimes W$ to construct an isomorphism from $V\otimes W$ to $\mathbb R^{d_1}\times\mathbb R^{d_2}.$

Comment: related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $V$ is $n$-dimensional and that $W$ is $m$-dimensional, then $V \otimes W$ is $mn$-dimensional. Indeed, assuming that $V$ has a basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and that $W$ has a basis $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^m$, then you can show that $V\otimes W$ has a basis $\{e_i\otimes f_j\}_{i,j}$, and so it's $mn$-dimensional. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78564/basis-for-tensor-products). Your claim then follows from the fact that any $mn$-dimensional normed space (over $\mathbb{R}$) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ (see van Neerven, J. (2022). Functional analysis (Vol. 201). Cambridge University Press, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over the field $\Bbb{R}$ of the real numbers  saying

$\text{dim}(V) = n$ and $\text{dim}(W) = m \qquad n,m \in \Bbb{N}$

Their tensor-product has the dimension

$\text{dim}(V \otimes W) = n \cdot m$

as stated in S. Lang: Algebra, Revised third edition, p.609, Cor. 2.4.

Because two finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic iff they have equal dimension there will be **an** isomorphism, but this isomorphism has not to be necessarily unique.

So, the vectors of the tensor-product can be regarded als $n\cdot m$ tuples of real numbers, but they are not real numbers for their own. The vector space structure is that of a tensor-product with its universal property.

Comment: Do you mind expanding your last paragraph? If $V \otimes W$ is a vector space of dimensionality $n\cdot m$ why the elements of it are not real valued vectors with $n\cdot m$ components?

Comment: @Tumirsito What OlafZ means by "can be regarded as $n\cdot m$ tuples" is that there's a one-to-one correspondence between the elements of $V\otimes W$ and the set of real valued vectors with $m\cdot n$ components. There being a one-to-one correspondence doesn't mean that the elements of $V\otimes W$ are actually real vectors with $n\cdot m$ components.

Comment: @Turmirsito Take the sets $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{a,b,c\}$. There's a one-to-one correspondence, i.e. a bijection, between them. It doesn't mean, however, that the elements of $A$ are letters.

Comment: @Oscar Got it thanks oscar, now, what I'm still missing is what is an element of $V\otimes W$?  Since there exists an isomorphism between $V\otimes W$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n\cdot m}$ under what condition (under what isomorphism i guess?) can i interpret the elements of $V\otimes W$ as elements of $\mathbb{R}^{n\cdot m}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ be bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively. The tensor product space $V\otimes W$ is a vector space with basis from objects (vectors in the product space) of form $v_i \otimes w_j$ for $1\leq i \leq n$, $1\leq j\leq m$. Thus dimension of $V\otimes W$ is $nm$.

To make things less abstract, if $V,W$ were space of column vectors with $n,m$  entries in $\mathbb{R}$, tensor product is the space spanned by $n\times m$ matrices $E_{ij}$ whose $ij$th enry is $1$ and else is $0$. Thus dimension is $nm$.

Now, I think the word you are looking for is canonical or natural, which to me it the one above, but the set of isomorphisms between two same dimensional vector spaces over the same fields is a group, and in case of $\mathbb{R}$ there is not just single such isomorphism. (e.g if $A$ is such isomorphism, so is $2A$).

Comment: Ok i think i got it. Therefore yes, any element of $V\otimes W$ can be a vector on $\mathbb{R}^{d^2}$ but its not unique. Example with the matrix, i can transform the matrix to be a d=4 vector by taking the elements from up to down , left to right, but I could also take the elements on the other order, both cases will be an insomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: Yes. But following is really what you want probably: map $v_i \otimes w_j \rightarrow a_i b_j^t$ where $a_i,b_j$'s span $n,m$ dimensional column spaces preserves distirbutive property $x\otimes (y + z) = x\otimes y + x \otimes z$ and is an isomorphism